# What is the term for collectibles which enhance storytelling (i.e. audio logs, bestiary entries, etc.)?

Tags: audio, terminology

For example, Borderlands uses ECHO logs, there are audio entries in BioShock, RPGs often have "books" that you can collect pages to read a mini bonus story.

Is there a term more specific than "collectible" which conveys the element of storytelling?

Comment: If there isn't, I suggest we call them "narrative nuggets".

Comment: @NeomerArcana Make it an answer, then the votes will decide what they're called.

Answer (score 3):

In general, when these are not necessarily collectibles, they’re called the [environmental storytelling](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1012647/What-Happened-Here-Environmental).

Specifically for collectibles, I have seen “[narrative collectibles](https://www.google.fr/search?num=50&q="narrative+collectibles")” used here and there. Other options may include: narrative objects, collectible narrative objects, story collectibles.

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't, I suggest we call them "narrative nuggets"

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a more general term, Tynan Sylvester refers to details which provide flavor but don't directly impact the main gameplay as "Hair Complexity."

> Hair complexity is my term for pieces of the simulation that don’t
>   affect anything outside themselves.
>
> I call it hair complexity because it sticks off the main ball of
>   relationships without feeding back into it, like the hair on your
>   head. Such hair complexity can be ignored by players who don’t wish to
>   deal with it, while more interested or skilled players can pay
>   attention and get its full flavor. It’s like the flavortext in a card
>   game.

Source: [The Simulation Dream](http://tynansylvester.com/2013/06/the-simulation-dream/)